# redirect directories to subdomain directories

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently moved my old site to an archived subdomain, and I want the old posts to go to the new archive.

Example:

```
www.mysite.com/cat/blogpost1 
wwww.mysite.com/cat2/blogpost1 
www.mysite.com/cat3/subcat1/blogpost3
```

to

```
archive.mysite.com/cat/blogpost1
archive.mysite.com/cat2/blogpost1
archive.mysite.com/cat3/subcat1/blogpost3
```

I tried using an answer I found on the forum

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?soulculture\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d+/ necropolis.soulculture.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

but it still goes to the original link.

As I'll still be posting on the new site with categories and such, I was wondering if it'd be possible to only redirect links with those specific categories.

Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks in advance.